# No Script Errors - Character doesnt jump - Unity 3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

Currently building a 2D game, and have created a javascript code for the jump for my character 'Ezio' but it does not do anything when i press 'space' for it to jump. There are no errors with the code either.

```
#pragma strict
var jump :float = 0; 
var jumpspeed : float = 15; 
var jumptimer :float = 0; 
function Start () {
}
function Update () {
    if (jump == 1) {
        jumptimer = jumptimer +1;
        if (jumptimer >= 50) {
            jumptimer = 0;
            jump = 0;
        }
    }
}
if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space"))
{
    if (jump == 0) {
        rigidbody2D.velocity.y = jumpspeed;
        jump = 1;
    }
}
```

Any suggestions on what could be the issue?

Comment: Shouldn't `if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space"))
{` be inside `Update()`?

Comment: As it is right now, the code doesn't do the check to see if the space key is pressed down since that `if (Input.GetKeyDown ("space")) {` statement is not run each time `Uodate()`, as far as I can see.

Comment: use c#, it solves all your problems ;D

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#pragma strict
var jump :float = 0; 
var jumpspeed : float = 15; 
var jumptimer :float = 0; 
function Start () {
}


function Update() {

    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {

        if (jump == 1) {
            jumptimer = jumptimer + 1;
            if (jumptimer >= 50) {
                jumptimer = 0;
                jump = 0;
            }
        } else {
            rigidbody2D.velocity.y = jumpspeed;
            jump = 1;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just a few additions: * Use a boolean for jump and name it jumping * use Time.deltaTime to count the jumptimer and set the 50 to a value in seconds * Also this probably should get into FixedUpate because you are using the physics engine.

Comment: @Tom sounds like very good tips. Feel free to add those stuff to my answer :)

Comment: HI Daniel, 

Many thanks for this, however, having some additional problems with the script.When pressing space bar, the character only jumps like half a cm off the ground, and unable to jump after that. I have set the "jump" to 2, which allows for additional jumps but it can be abused by simply continually pressing space bar.

Comment: any suggestions how to fix this? Many Thanks

Comment: Ok ignore the above. Jump distance has been fixed, only issue remaining is when i press jump, it only jumps once?

Comment: @user3533784 I'm not too good with UnityScript, but maybe this will do the trick:`rigidbody2D.velocity.y += jumpspeed;`?

Comment: Hi Daniel,

This definately sorts out the height issue, just the issue with it only jumping once. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3533784 you want to jump multiple times mid air?

Comment: @user3533784 perhaps this thread can help you (although they seem to use a different method to move the character): http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/176879/double-jump.html

Comment: Not quite. When the character is on the ground, he can rejump.

Comment: @user3533784 then what should happen when the character is on the ground?

Comment: the character is standing on the ground as default. Think of it like super mario, just simply want the character to be able to rejump once hes back on the ground after jumping if that makes sense?

Comment: @user3533784 ok, I think I understand now. I will be out for a few hours now but after that I'll try to fix that.

Comment: @user3533784 so now, when the player has jumped once and landed, he cannot jump more?